# PostgreSQL and apache - Faulting module

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

Im just installed Postgresql 9.6 and created the server by pgAdmin 4(on Win 2012R2). I created DB and used pg_dump to import table from another server.

```
pg_dump -U postgres Test < test.pgsql
```

The web server i'm using is Apache 2.4.27.0. Im trying after that to connect to db test with PHP file. And there is the problem in event viewer :

```
    Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.27.0, time stamp: 0x59616b7b
Faulting module name: libintl-8.dll, version: 0.19.4.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000067e2
Faulting process id: 0xd24
Faulting application start time: 0x01d320befcc84638
Faulting application path: D:\WEB_Server\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: D:\WEB_Server\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin\libintl-8.dll
Report Id: c47e5ac2-8cb2-11e7-93fc-000c296b33a1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Can you help me to fix the problem?

here is the output of the Apache error.log(in first the size of the file wa 1GB and i deleted it because its says that cant view it):

```
    [Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.686558 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.905287 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.905287 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.905287 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00456: Server built: Jul  8 2017 16:32:10
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.905287 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\WEB_Server\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/WEB_Server/Apache24'
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:26.905287 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3692
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:27.389682 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3692:tid 328] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:27.545915 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3692:tid 328] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:30:27.545915 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3692:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:01.624105 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00428: Parent: child process 3692 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.014722 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.030347 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.030347 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00456: Server built: Jul  8 2017 16:32:10
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.030347 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\WEB_Server\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/WEB_Server/Apache24'
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.030347 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1152
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.592895 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1152:tid 332] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.811604 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1152:tid 332] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:02.827231 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1152:tid 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.014810 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00428: Parent: child process 1152 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.514787 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.530428 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.530428 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00456: Server built: Jul  8 2017 16:32:10
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.530428 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\WEB_Server\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/WEB_Server/Apache24'
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:31.530428 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 436] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4064
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:32.046058 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4064:tid 328] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:32.374232 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4064:tid 328] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 15:31:32.389886 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4064:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: In the pgadmin a cant see the tables that i imported from pg_dump. The database is empty...

Comment: Can you show the content of the apache log file? preferably the error.log

Comment: Sure. This is the new file that is generated after i deleted the 1GB one

Comment: Not sure what is wrong. It seems that your server is constantly been restarted. The log indicates only that a possible problem is on the SSL configuration of the server, every time it try to start it it fails. Is this the log after you run your application? Take a look in the other log files see if there is something relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that i`m trying to view table who does not exist causing crashing a module. Is this a normal crash? Why php dont prompt me that the table does not exist?